# VS Code Extension Sidebar Not Displaying/Loading

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04

I'm simply wanting to search for extensions in VS Code, so that I can look at a file produced by sqlite3. I go to the extensions tab and click on it but I cannot search for anything. As shown in the screenshot below there is EXTENSIONS to the top left but there is no search bar at all. I cannot click in it or right click in it to bring anything up and I don't know if there is any alternative to search for and get the extension I need.

[Screenshot showing Extensions View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA5w1.png)

I am working on a Ubuntu 18.04LTS OS and I've opened VS Code through Anaconda Navigator (1.9.12). The version of VS Code is 1.45.1. I thought that maybe something here was out of date but I've checked that and they seem to be up-to-date. I've also tried to search for something that's like my problem and the only thing I can find is this issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/71574 which was resolved by updating to the most recent versions (I have the most recent versions). I've also tried opening VS Code simply via the terminal but I still have the same problem with the Extensions side bar.